# Multiple operations in same column on Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have MySql Query :

```
select * from transactions where request_shipping_date  = '2020-11-25' and  status = 'paid' or 'on_process' or 'finish';
```

and I got `44 Rows`

and  I Want Convert to Eloquent Model :

```
$request_shipping_date = Carbon::now()->addDays(1)->format('Y-m-d');
 $data = Order::with('order_details')
                ->where('request_shipping_date', 'like', $request_shipping_date.'%')
                ->Where('status', 'paid')
                ->orWhere('status', 'on_process')
                ->orWhere('status', 'finish')
                ->get();
```

and i got : `24025 Rows`

Is there any wrong ?

Comment: where('request_shipping_date', '=', $request_shipping_date)

Comment: @NgôMinh Still the same sir,..

Comment: You should try with `->whereIn('status', ['paid', 'on_process', 'finish'])`. Your current query is doing `WHERE request_shipping_date like ... AND status = 'paid' OR status = 'on_process' OR status = 'finish'`, meaning you'll grab any row with 'on_process' or 'finish', no matter the shipping date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The no of rows retrieved changes because of the `like` operator when comparing dates

Try using the below

```php
$request_shipping_date = Carbon::now()->addDays(1)->format('Y-m-d');

$data = Order::with('order_details')
                ->whereDate('request_shipping_date', $request_shipping_date)
                ->Where('status', 'paid')
                ->orWhere('status', 'on_process')
                ->orWhere('status', 'finish')
                ->get();
```

You could also rephrase the eloquent query as

```php
$request_shipping_date = Carbon::now()->addDays(1)->format('Y-m-d');

$data = Order::with('order_details')
    ->whereDate('request_shipping_date', $request_shipping_date)
    ->whereIn('status', ['paid', 'on_process', 'finish'])
    ->get();
```

Comment: whereIn('status', ['paid', 'on_process', 'finish'] is work,.. but not with where or where

Comment: Try to replace `get()` with `toSql()` and compare the sql query with what you have as MysQL query if there's any difference you can know what needs to be changed

Comment: @MuamarHumaidi To understand why it doesn't work with `where and orWhere` replace `get()` with `toSql()` and then `dd($data)` to get the sql query generated by eloquent statements and then compare it with your MySQL statement